# MATLAB quad function not work for constant function?

Tags: matlab

I want to use the quad function to do the integration today. I wrote a function file:

> > function z=pdf_y1(x)
> >     z=100;

And then, in the command line, I type:

> > quad('pdf_y1',0,0.5)

The output is:
??? Error using ==> quad at 79
The integrand function must return an output vector of the same length as the input vector.

I tried z=2*x. It works. I don't know why quad is not working for constant case. I actually want to use it on some other functions involving if-else statements. But it keeps showing the same message: The integrand function must return an output vector of the same length as the input vector.

I don't know why. Could somebody help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function z=pdf_y1(x) z=100*ones(size(x))
```

MATLAB requires the output to be the same shape/dimension as the input for functions passed to `quad()`.